# Grayscale PNG writing from BufferedImage using PNGJ - hightest-level approach

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage

I just want to, at first, use PNGJ at the highest possible level to write a grayscale PNG with bit-depth 8.
I am working from a BufferedImage. Here's a snippet of the code used:

```
BufferedImage scaledBI;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
ImageInfo imi = new ImageInfo(scaledBI.getWidth(), scaledBI.getHeight(), 8, false, true, false);
PngWriter pngw = new PngWriter(baos, imi);
pngw.setCompLevel(3);
DataBufferByte db =((DataBufferByte) scaledBI.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
byte[] dbbuf = db.getData();
ImageLineByte line = new ImageLineByte(imi, dbbuf);

for (int row = 0; row < imi.rows; row++) {
    pngw.writeRow(line, row);
}
pngw.end();
return baos.toByteArray();
```

The original image is in j2k and is a palm print scan. The PNG looks similar to the background of the j2k with some vertical gray lines of different shades.
I tried the same buffered image data with ImageIO:

```
ImageIO.write(scaledBI, "png", baos);
```

and com.pngencoder.PngEncoder:

```
new PngEncoder().withBufferedImage(scaledBI).withCompressionLevel(3).toStream(baos);
```

which both render the image properly.
The long term aim is to improve on the speed offered by ImageIO and PngEncoder (which doesn't support grayscale).
I am stuck on just trying to run PNGJ with all default settings. I looked at the snippets in [PNGJ Wiki Snippets](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/wiki/Snippets) and the test code but I couldn't find a simple example with grayscale without scanline or chunk manipulation.
Looking at the PNGJ code it seems like we are properly going through block deflation row after row. What am I missing here?

Comment: you haven't even tagged   pngj - how  am I supposed  to  understand  what you  are  doing -   well  wishes to   the   long  term aims though

Comment: How large are your images?  I suspect keeping multiple copies of the image data in memory may have a bigger effect on speed than the choice of image encoder.

Comment: Hi @VGR, the image I am using has a height of 7200 and a width of 5000, so the byte array has size 36,000,000.

Comment: Hi @gpasch, pngj does not exist as a tag, and I am not reputable enough to create it.

Answer (score 0):

my problem sprung from my misunderstanding of what ImageLineByte stores, although as the name suggests it deals with a line, not the entire image data. I got confused by the fact that it references the image info. So my output was fine once I used ImageByteLine for each line:

```
for (int row = 0, offset = 0; row < imi.rows; row++) {
  int newOffset = offset + imi.cols;
  byte[] lineBuffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(dbbuf, offset, newOffset);
  ImageLineByte line = new ImageLineByte(imi, lineBuffer);
  pngw.writeRow(line, row);
  offset = newOffset;
}
```

Sorry for the trouble.